# When is an authorization request in Jabber purged?

Tags: jabber

I've sent an authorization request in Jabber but got no answer. I suppose that the request lives for a while on the Jabber server where I have registered my account or on the Jabber server where the person I'm trying to get to authorize me registered his account, if it's not the same server (this is probably not relevant to my question).

For how long will my authorization request live before it gets purged?

I don't want to spam the network with new authorization requests everyday, yet I want to maximize the chances to reach that person by sending a new authorization request as soon as the previous one expires.